# Мне нужно задать фиксированный размер кнопок, но при этом, я не хочу чтобы расстояние между ними тоже было фиксированным

Tags: c++, qt5

Мне нужно задать фиксированный размер кнопок, но при этом, я не хочу чтобы расстояние между ними тоже было фиксированным.[image]

```
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include "buttons.h"
#include "vertical_box.h"

Buttons::Buttons(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent) {

        auto *vbox = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        auto *hbox = new QHBoxLayout();

        snap = new QPushButton("Snap", this);
        flatpack = new QPushButton("Flatpack", this);
        appimage = new QPushButton("Appimage", this);

        vbox->addWidget(snap, 2, Qt::AlignTop);
        vbox->addWidget(flatpack, 1, Qt::AlignTop);
        vbox->addWidget(appimage, 0, Qt::AlignTop);

        //hbox->addWidget(snap, 0, Qt::AlignLeft);
        //hbox->addWidget(flatpack, 0, Qt::AlignLeft);
        //hbox->addWidget(appimage, 0, Qt::AlignLeft);
        
        vbox->addStretch(2);
        hbox->addStretch(1);
        vbox->addLayout(hbox);
    }
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#size-prop

Comment: Или в редакторе - справа таблица свойств выбранного объекта